# Among them or themselves

Tags: grammar, pronouns, reflexive-pronouns

Please look at the following:

Unlike western systems of philosophy, in India, the various branches co-existed over centuries, and sometimes evolved after intense debates ***among them***.

Why has ***among themselves*** not been used in the above? What difference would the usage of among themselves make in the above sentence?

Comment: Since the intended sense is ***between** them* *(them = the various branches of philosophy)* it's better to have non-reflexive ***them***. Using ***themselves*** here would tend to carry the implication that the various debates might have been conducted wholly or in part *within* each of those various branches, but pragmatically the intended sense is probably that the debates were  primarily between *different* branches.of philosophy.

Answer (score 7):

One could take **among themselves** to mean that the debates were held within the various branches intramurally rather than between the branches.

Consider:

> There were various delegations in the auditorium, debating among
>   themselves which candidate to vote for.

I would take that to mean that each delegation was having its own debate, not that there was an open floor debate.

On the other hand, debating *among them* would mean there was an open debate, the delegations debating each other.